# Sound playback came from java REST service ends prematurely in iOS Safari and Chrome

Tags: java, ios, iphone, rest, audio

A sound playback (600 KB) came from javax.ws.rs service ends prematurely in iPhone 8, 6 with iOS 12.1 for both Safari and Chrome browsers.

The same http link works perfectly from any desktop browser both windows and mac os and Android devices.

The link I use looks like: http://localhost:8080/myapp/recording.mp3

Tried to process Range header appropriately and send Accept-Ranges and Content-Range headers to a client with HTTP 206.

The backend looks like:

```
@GET
@Path("/recording")
@Produces("audio/mpeg")
public Response getTestRecording() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("/path/to/file/recording.mp3");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    return Response.ok(fis).status(200).header(CONTENT_LENGTH, file.length()).build();
}
```

Have anybody experienced the same behavior?